# current through capacitor in Laplace form

Tags: current, laplace-transform

We know that current through capacitor is i(t)=c*dv(t)/dt but what if we want the current through capacitor expressed in Laplace form ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBKpgV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here we convert 2F into Laplace as 1/2*s but what after then?
Assume that i current flows through capacitor .

Answer (score 2):

At least two ways of looking at this:

1. The Laplace representation of the capacitor's reactance is \$\frac{1}{sC}\$, hence for a voltage, \$\small V(s)\$ across \$\small C\$, the current through \$\small C\$, by Ohm's law, will be \$\small I(s)=sC\:V(s)\$
2. Differentiation in the time domain is equivalent to multiplying by \$\small s\$ in the Laplace domain. Therefore \$\frac{dv}{dt}\small \rightarrow sV(s)\$, and the differential equation transforms to: \$\small I(s) = C\:sV(s)\$

Zero initial conditions have been assumed.

Comment: yes this was what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Remember that s = \$2\pi f\$ so if the frequency is 1 Hz then the impedance is \$\dfrac{1}{2\times 2\pi \times 1}\$ = 0.0796 ohms (reactive).

If the applied voltage is a 1 Hz sinewave of amplitude 1 V RMS then current is 12.57 amps.

If the applied current is a 1 Hz sinewave of amplitude 1 A RMS then the voltage will be 0.0796 volts.